# How can I use unittest.mock to remove side effects from code?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, exception, python-unittest.mock

I have a function with several points of failure:

```
def setup_foo(creds):
    """
    Creates a foo instance with which we can leverage the Foo virtualization
    platform.

    :param creds: A dictionary containing the authorization url, username,
                  password, and version associated with the Foo
                  cluster.
    :type creds:  dict
    """

    try:
        foo = Foo(version=creds['VERSION'],
                  username=creds['USERNAME'],
                  password=creds['PASSWORD'],
                  auth_url=creds['AUTH_URL'])

        foo.authenticate()
        return foo
    except (OSError, NotFound, ClientException) as e:
        raise UnreachableEndpoint("Couldn't find auth_url {0}".format(creds['AUTH_URL']))
    except Unauthorized as e:
        raise UnauthorizedUser("Wrong username or password.")
    except UnsupportedVersion as e:
        raise Unsupported("We only support Foo API with major version 2")
```

and I'd like to test that all the relevant exceptions are caught (albeit not handled well currently).

I have an initial test case that passes:

```
def test_setup_foo_failing_auth_url_endpoint_does_not_exist(self):
    dummy_creds = {
        'AUTH_URL' : 'http://bogus.example.com/v2.0',
        'USERNAME' : '', #intentionally blank.
        'PASSWORD' : '', #intentionally blank.
        'VERSION'  : 2 
    }
    with self.assertRaises(UnreachableEndpoint):
        foo = osu.setup_foo(dummy_creds)
```

but how can I make my test framework believe that the AUTH_URL is actually a valid/reachable URL?

I've created a mock class for `Foo`:

```
class MockFoo(Foo):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

and my thought is mock the call to `setup_foo` and remove the side effect of raising an `UnreachableEndpoint` exception. I know how to *add* side-effects to a `Mock` with `unittest.mock`, but how can I remove them?

Comment: You are looking to test the other exceptions, so it does not matter in your tests whether it is in fact a *real* URL. What you want to know is how your code *behaves* when it raises the exceptions you are looking to catch, so just make your context manager raise the exception that you want to test. Ultimately, just re-use your same method but for each of the different exceptions and test to make sure your code behaves with respect to those exceptions the client will raise

Comment: @idjaw What if the exceptions are thrown in a certain order; i.e., first check if valid url (throw if not), then check if authorized (throw if not), etc.?

Comment: Why would order matter, though? if an exception is raised in the given instance of usage, your code wants to catch it at that given time and behave accordingly.

Comment: @idjaw That's exactly my intent -- mock the use case where the URL is valid, but the other credentials are not.

Comment: It would be best if I illustrated this for you in an answer. I understand what you are trying to do now.

Comment: @idjaw Sorry if my question was poorly asked... :)

Comment: No no. The question was fine. It's just hard to answer it in just a little comment. :) However, being familiar with nova, dealing with client exceptions upon invoking a client is tough to grab exceptions on until you actually make a call. What is your authenticate method doing exactly? I'm assuming it's the `authenticate` method that will raise?

Comment: @idjaw Yes, so I suppose one approach is to completely remove the `foo.authenticate()` call and only test the reachability/version in `setup_foo` and then test `authenticate` in another method. But yes, the `authenticate` will raise. As you know, nova doesn't attempt to auth until a request is made, so `authenticate` is a dummy request.

Comment: Let me know if you need clarification in what I wrote. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your exceptions are being raised from `foo.authenticate()`, what you want to realize here is that it does not necessarily matter whether the data is in fact *really* valid in your tests. What you are trying to say really is this:

When this external method raises with something, my code should behave accordingly based on that something.

So, with that in mind, what you want to do is have different test methods where you pass what *should* be valid data, and have your code react accordingly. The data itself does not matter, but it provides a documented way of showing how the code should behave with data that is passed in that way.

Ultimately, you should not care how the nova client handles the data you give it (nova client is tested, and you should not care about it). What you care about is what it spits back at you and how you want to handle it, regardless of what you gave it.

In other words, for the sake of your tests, you can actually pass a dummy url as:

```
"this_is_a_dummy_url_that_works"
```

For the sake of your tests, you can let that pass, because in your `mock`, you will raise accordingly.

For example. What you should be doing here is actually mocking out `Client` from `novaclient`. With that mock in hand, you can now manipulate whatever call within novaclient so you can properly test your code.

This actually brings us to the root of your problem. Your first exception is catching the following:

```
except (OSError, NotFound, ClientException)
```

The problem here, is that you are now catching `ClientException`. Almost every exception in `novaclient` inherits from `ClientException`, so no matter what you try to test beyond that exception line, you will never reach those exceptions. You have two options here. Catch `ClientException`, and just raise a custom exception, or, remote `ClientException`, and be more explicit (like you already are).

So, let us go with removing `ClientException` and set up our example accordingly.

So, in your *real* code, you should be now setting your first exception line as:

```
except (OSError, NotFound) as e:
```

Furthermore, the next problem you have is that you are not mocking properly. You are supposed to mock with respect to where you are testing. So, if your `setup_nova` method is in a module called `your_nova_module`. It is with respect to that, that you are supposed to mock. The example below illustrates all this.

```
@patch("your_nova_module.Client", return_value=Mock())
def test_setup_nova_failing_unauthorized_user(self, mock_client):
    dummy_creds = {
        'AUTH_URL': 'this_url_is_valid',
        'USERNAME': 'my_bad_user. this should fail',
        'PASSWORD': 'bad_pass_but_it_does_not_matter_what_this_is',
        'VERSION': '2.1',
        'PROJECT_ID': 'does_not_matter'
    }

    mock_nova_client = mock_client.return_value
    mock_nova_client.authenticate.side_effect = Unauthorized(401)

    with self.assertRaises(UnauthorizedUser):
        setup_nova(dummy_creds)
```

So, the main idea with the example above, is that it does not matter what data you are passing. What really matters is that you are wanting to know how your code will react when an external method raises.

So, our goal here is to actually raise something that will get your second exception handler to be tested: `Unauthorized`

This code was tested against the code you posted in your question. The only modifications were made were with module names to reflect my environment.

Comment: _nova client is tested, and you should not care about it_ 
hahahahaaaaaaa... :) Thanks for such a great answer!

Comment: hehe :) Just to clarify that, by not care, I meant with respect to your own unittests, you assume that novaclient will handle whatever you give it as expected and you deal with what it should return.

Comment: FWIW, I'm using the novaclient directly, but wanted to make my question more platform-agnostic. :) `novaclient.v2.client.Client` has an `authenticate` method.

Comment: @erip You're right. I just checked, and am actually changing one of my methods to use the `authenticate` method instead. Which in turn means I am going to update my unittests for the case of using `authenticate` now. :)

Comment: This may be a silly question, but how would I define `authenticate_mock`? I would imagine that I could just declare `authenticate_mock=foo.authenticate` with `@patch(foo.Foo.authenticate)`, but when I do this, I find my assertions aren't raised.

Comment: @erip Updated with a functional sample example to illustrate how it works. You can easily apply it to your scenario.

Comment: OK, this actually doesn't seem to work exactly. I'm raising an `UnauthorizedUser` successfully in my `authenticate`, but while that's happening, `UnreachableEndpoint` is still being raised because the URL isn't valid. :( See [here](http://ideone.com/fxNDr1) for the test and the stacktrace.

Comment: Ah. That means you still have other things to mock in your method that are trying to run for real. Whatever it is that is raising invalid url, you have to mock out. Use a patch decorator as well to mock out whatever that method is that is being run for real.

Comment: So I guess that goes back to my original question -- is there a way to just "remove" side-effects? Otherwise I have to dig deep in their code to find the exceptions.

Comment: I'm not in front of my machine to modify things right now. But, I know what is happening. You want to patch your call to `Client` (the novaclient Client call). The return_value of that will be `Mock()`. I hope that is clear. From there with a mocked out nova_client Client call, you can then set whatever return values and side effects you need to to properly test.

Comment: I guess I'm still not exactly seeing how that will help. Return values aren't so concerning to me. Mocking requires extending, which will still raise the exceptions.

Comment: Is the code you are testing pretty much what you have in your question? When I'm able to get to my desktop I can write up a quick example to show you how it will work.

Comment: The Ideone contains my test verbatim. :)

Comment: I was referring to the non-test code that you want to test.

Comment: Yes, the code in my post is what I'm testing. Note that the raised exceptions are custom exceptions, but they just inherit from `Exception`.

Comment: @erip Yep, that's fine. When I get a chance I'll illustrate what I'm trying to show, hopefully it will clarify. But if I may provide another detail in my explanation that might help you  move forward. The idea with mocking the nova client here, is that the return object of that `Client` call will be a `Mock` which is *exactly* what you want. Remember, you are testing the behaviour of your code. So you want to manipulate/control how nova client will behave so you know how your code should react.

Comment: I have the solution worked out. But I actually found out why you have been having problems. Your first exception is catching `ClientException`. Everything is a `ClientException` in Nova. You will never get to the other two exceptions, because everything inherits from `ClientException`. I'm going to update my code to reflect the updated code to showcase mocking the Client instead. But that is ultimately the root of your problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to mock out http servers from bogus urls, I suggest you check out [HTTPretty](https://github.com/gabrielfalcao/HTTPretty). It mocks out urls at a socket level so it can trick most Python HTTP libraries that it's a valid url.

I suggest the following setup for your unittest:

```
class FooTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        httpretty.register_uri(httpretty.GET, "http://bogus.example.com/v2.0",
                       body='[{"response": "Valid"}]',
                       content_type="application/json")
    @httpretty.activate
    def test_test_case(self):
        resp = requests.get("http://bogus.example.com/v2.0")
        self.assertEquals(resp.status_code, 200)
```

Note that the mock will only apply to stacks that are decorated with `http.activate` decorator, so it won't leak to other places in your code that you don't want to mock. Hope that makes sense.